# How to get _value properties in Vue 3 ref

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, ref

Hi I'm trying to get values from the _value property in Vue to no avail. How am I able to grab these values like **accessKey**, **align**, **ariaAtomic** etc. I'm trying to get the **clientWidth**.

[image]

```
  <div id="hello" ref="theRange" class="border-red-200 border-2 w-[80px]">
   <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>

  const theRange = ref(null);
  console.log(theRange.value.clientWidth); // Throws error
```

Comment: perhaps you need to wait for the component to be mounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get it

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const cube = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(cube.value.clientWidth)
})
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="cube">nice</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: orange;
  }
</style>
```

Here is [an example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpNUUFuwyAQ/MqKSxwpwVF7cx1LfUDPvXBx8MYmxSwCnLSK/PcudlrlgMTu7OwMw128ey+vE4pK1FEH4xNETJNvlDOjp5DgDgHPOyD3QZNL2MEM50AjbJi1UU45TS4m0NMJ4ZhnCzdZu83IP6cotnBs4K4cQB4ni9JSX2SSvLZ2QqmtQZc+TZcG5s586nI1xFa4SDh62ybkCqDuzDVLHZXIK5RonNFYl9xmvC6fhrmM6cciRE0eu4We2YsXgFsWrODlcPDfb2trQNMPqYLXp96p1V994Md0e02WQgUUWtfjAs+L1yzSiJ1YY9uPrZeXSI6DXaTUA4hKVH/iSnCGuVZiSMnHqizjWefvuERJoS/5JgMnaEaUGMf9KdAtYuDFSjyUZzH/AvzFnEk=).

[image]

---

Regarding [Vue's lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram), `setup()` doesn't have the element attached to the DOM yet, hence why you may not have anything regarding window-related properties of your object.

Comment: this is ostensibly like the code the OP presented - how does this provide any help? (yes, I know, you access the ref inside onMounted, but you don't make it clear that's the solution) :p

Comment: @JaromandaX we also don't have a proper code snippet/context to see that it's not working. My solution here is more of a "nah, it should work, check your syntax again" than an actual in-depth explanation. I guess I can add the lifecycle for sure.

Comment: OK. Fair enough :p